Percentage of values between 3 standard deviations and 4 standard deviations.
After learning about the empirical rule / $68-95-99.7$ rule, I am just wondering about the percentage of values $4$ standard deviations from the mean.
This question is pretty much the same as the Percentage of values between $3$ standard deviations and $4$ standard deviations.
I know this will be clearly less than $0.15\%$. If anyone answers, their help will be appreciated.

The value is $99.99366575$%

@Peter Thank you.

I know what you indicate , @Peter , though the number OP is wanting here is very small.

According to https://blog.masterofproject.com/six-sigma-statistics/ :
$\pm 1 \sigma : 68\%$
$\pm 2 \sigma : 95\%$
$\pm 3 \sigma : 99.73\%$
$\pm 4 \sigma : 99.9937\%$
$\pm 5 \sigma : 99.99994\%$
$\pm 6 \sigma : 99.9999998\%$
Hence , Percentage of values between $\pm 3 \sigma$ & $\pm 4 \sigma$ is :
$$99.9937\%-99.73\% \approx 0.2637\%$$
Pictorially :


Is there a formula for this, or are these values just known?

There is no simple easy formula. Similar to trig tables & log tables , there are accurate tables ( earlier generated manually & now generated with Computers ) which we have to use in Statistics.

Thank you for the help!
